# Automate partitioning a disk using DISKPART and prompting user for disk or quit

Tags: windows, batch-file, disk-partitioning

I need to create a batch file which partitions and formats a USB drive.  This is to create a Windows 7 USB boot disk.

DISKPART is the tool used and you pass it instructions as in:

DISKPART /s instructions.txt

In my case I want my instructions to look like this:

```
example prepdisk.txt
SELECT DISK <Prompt user to either enter a number or q for quit>
CLEAN
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
FORMAT QUICK FS=NTFS LABEL="Windows"
ACTIVE
ASSIGN LETTER="C"
```

Then I would have a batch file like this:

prepdisk.bat:

```
DISKPART /s prepdisk.txt
```

But I am stuck on how to prompt the user for a disk id.  I also want to be able to quit if unsure because obviously formatting the wrong drive could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `set /?` help. You will need to use `set /p var=promptText` to ask a user for input. What the user types will be stored in the indicated variable.

`Diskpart` accepts commands from a script file and from stdin. So we can pipe commands to it to show information to the user and check the selection.

Use this as a base (save as a `.cmd` file) and adapt to your needs.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:ask
    rem select disk to format
    call :showDiskTable
    set /p "diskNumber=Type number of disk to format: " || goto :processCancelled

    rem test disk selection
    (   echo select disk %diskNumber%
        echo list disk
    ) | diskpart | findstr /b /c:"*" >nul || (
        echo(
        echo WRONG SELECTION
        echo(
        goto :ask
    )

    rem confirm disk selection
    cls
    call :showDiskTable
    set "answer=%random%%random%"
    set /p "confirm=If you are sure you want to format disk %diskNumber%, type %answer%:"
    if not "%confirm%"=="%answer%" goto :processCancelled

    rem Create script file
    set "scriptFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"
    > "%scriptFile%" (
        echo SELECT DISK %diskNumber%
        echo CLEAN
        echo CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
        echo FORMAT QUICK FS=NTFS LABEL="Windows"
        echo ACTIVE
        echo ASSIGN LETTER="C"
    )

    rem execute script file
    type "%scriptFile%"
    rem diskpart /s "%scriptFile%"

    rem cleanup and exit
    del /q "%scriptFile%"

    echo(
    echo DONE
    echo(

    exit /b 0

:showDiskTable
    echo =====================================================
    echo list disk | diskpart | findstr /b /c:" "
    echo =====================================================
    echo(
    goto :eof

:processCancelled
    echo(
    echo PROCESS CANCELLED
    echo(
    exit /b 1
```

Note that for testing the `diskpart /s file` is disabled and the script generated is only echoed to console. When everything works as intended, remove the `type` line (not needed) and the `rem` before the `diskpart`

Comment: Hi find this script very useful and would like to use for partitioning. I am just trying migrate myself from Linux. However, would like to know what would be best possible way list only "diskdrives" not USB drives. If you could provide me snippet it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Interesting to me, but if you write:

```
set /a disknr=0
```

then execute:

```
diskpart /s list.txt
```

when list.txt contains:

```
select disk %disknr%
list part
```

you get the same good result.